# updated sdk today since then not been able to do an

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated the android sdk today - since then I have had the following problems

1. stopped exporting apk ( but doesn't tell me why)
2. can't run emulator (message on console says it cannot find *.apk)
3. I tried reloading project, after getting message that id did not exist (even though it was there)
4. managed to get eclipse to recognise project, but now it rejects the switch/case statement on my options menu

All this worked yesterday - and I have looked at most of the solutions put forward on other posts - and none seem to work.

currently I am on android sdk tools 23.05 and eclipse Luna 4.4.1 (running on Linux as that may be a factor)

Has anyone any idea how to solve this - any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try reinstalling the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: That may be an idea - but I may go the whole hog and reinstall elipse completely.  Alternatively I might import the project into android studio (which I also have installed - although unused) and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get things to work, although I was now getting an error related to case statements in libraries.  I checked the properties, and the project was not set as a library so I couldn't understand this.

I then tried the one thing I should have done first - what I would have done thirty years ago when first in IT - I completely rebooted the whole system.

Now eclipse showed the project as being a library, so I was able to reset that and everything now seems to work.

I can only assume the update yesterday messed up some of the memory, and the eclipse lost its bearings.